# update vue-chartjs yaxis max value without re rendering entire vue chart js

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am working on a project where I am implementing some charts from the Vue-Chartjs library. I need the Y-axis max value to change everytime the user changes the filters given. I Import an existing barchart from the vue-chartjs library. In the code there is a javascript file that has some defaults already, to set extra options I can use the extraOptions object as a prop to personalize each chart accordingly. Here is the default component:

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { hexToRGB } from "./utils";
import reactiveChartMixin from "./mixins/reactiveChart";

let defaultOptions = {
  tooltips: {
   tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
   tooltipFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
   tooltipFontSize: 14,
   tooltipFontStyle: "normal",
   tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
   tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
   tooltipTitleFontSize: 14,
   tooltipTitleFontStyle: "bold",
   tooltipTitleFontColor: "#fff",
   tooltipYPadding: 6,
   tooltipXPadding: 6,
   tooltipCaretSize: 8,
   tooltipCornerRadius: 6,
   tooltipXOffset: 10,
},
legend: {
  display: false
},
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      fontColor: "#9f9f9f",
      fontStyle: "bold",
      beginAtZero: true,
      display: false,
      min: 0,
      max: 100
    },
  gridLines: {
    display: false,
    drawBorder: false,
  }
}],
xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false,
    drawBorder: false,
   },
 }],
    }
   };
     export default {
        name: 'BarChart',
        extends: Bar,
        mixins: [reactiveChartMixin],
        props: {
        labels: {
        type: [Object, Array],
        description: 'Chart labels. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    datasets: {
      type: [Object, Array],
      description: 'Chart datasets. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    data: {
      type: [Object, Array],
      description: 'Chart.js chart data (overrides all default data)'
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      description: 'Chart color. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    extraOptions: {
      type: Object,
      description: 'Chart.js options'
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      description: 'Chart title'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    assignChartData() {
      let { gradientFill } = this.assignChartOptions(defaultOptions);
      let color = this.color || this.fallBackColor;
      return {
        labels: this.labels || [],
        datasets: this.datasets ? this.datasets : [{
          label: this.title || '',
          backgroundColor: gradientFill,
          borderColor: color,
          pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
          pointBackgroundColor: color,
          pointBorderWidth: 2,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 4,
          fill: true,
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: this.data || []
        }]
      }
    },
    assignChartOptions(initialConfig) {
      let color = this.color || this.fallBackColor;
      const ctx = document.getElementById(this.chartId).getContext('2d');
      const gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
      gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
      gradientFill.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB(color, 0.6));
      let extraOptions = this.extraOptions || {}
      return {
        ...initialConfig,
        ...extraOptions,
        gradientFill
      };
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chartData = this.assignChartData({});
    this.options = this.assignChartOptions(defaultOptions);
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options, this.extraOptions);
  }
}
```

I use this js file to import the bar chart inside a vue component like you see down below.
everytime the input of the form changes i need to re render the chart. I use the `onInputChange()` method to turn the boolean `loaded` to false and call the `loadData()` method.
Inside the `loadData()` method I make an axios request that gets me the right data every time. I also get the maximum value for my Y axis.

Then in the response I call on `updateChart()` so that I can update the data and the max value of the chart. then i turn the boolean `loaded` to true again so that my chart renders accordingly.

The problem with this approach is that the chart disappears completely for a split of a second. Before deciding to change the max Value of the Y axis I was able to update the data of my chart without having to use the v-if="loaded".

I need to find a solution where the chart re renders without it completely disappearing from the page. I know some suggested to use computed variables but i don't fully understand how it is supposed to work. Here is the component minus the form fields.

I guess in it's essence what I want is to update the Y axis max value without having to re render the entire chart.

```
 <template>
      <div>
          <BarChart v-if="loaded" :labels="chartLabels"
                 :datasets="datasets"
                 :height="100"
                 :extraOptions="extraOptions"
          >
          </BarChart>
        <br>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import BarChart from '../../components/Library/UIComponents/Charts/BarChart'
    import Dropdown from "../../components/Library/UIComponents/Dropdown"
    import GroupedMultiSelectWidget from "~/components/widgets/GroupedMultiSelectWidget"
    import SelectWidget from "../../components/widgets/SelectWidget";
    
    
    export default{
      name: 'PopularChart',
      components: {BarChart, Dropdown, SelectWidget, GroupedMultiSelectWidget},
      data(){
        return {
          loaded:true,
          form:{
              day: 'Today',
              workspace:'',
              machine_family: [],
              duration: [],
              user_group: [],
              dt_start:'',
              dt_end:''
          },
          url: `/api/data_app/job_count_by_hour/`,
          chart_data: [],
          days: [ {day:"Today", id:"Today"},
                  {day:"Monday", id:"0"},
                  {day:"Tuesday",id:"1"},
                  {day:"Wednesday",id:"2"},
                  {day:"Thursday",id:"3"},
                  {day:"Friday",id:"4"},
                  {day:"Saturday",id:"5"},
                  {day:"sunday",id:"6"} ],
          chartLabels: ["00u", "1u", "2u", "3u","4u","5u", "6u", "7u", "8u", "9u", "10u", "11u", "12u", "13u", "14u", "15u","16u", "17", "18u","19u","20u","21u","22u","23u"],
          datasets: [],
          maximumValue: '',
          extraOptions:{}
    
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onInputChange() {
          this.loaded = false
          this.loadData()
        },
        async loadData() {
            await this.$axios.get(`${this.url}?day=${this.form.day}&date_start=${this.form.dt_start}&date_end=${this.form.dt_end}&workspace=${this.form.workspace}&user_group=${this.form.user_group}&machine_family=${this.form.machine_family}`)
              .then(response => {
                this.updateChart(response.data.results,response.data.maximum)
                this.loaded = true
            })
        },
        updateChart(data,maxValue) {
            this.datasets = [{
                  label: ["jobs %"],
                  backgroundColor:"#f93232",
                  data: data
            },]
            this.maximumValue = maxValue
            this.extraOptions = {
              tooltips: {
                callbacks:{
                  label: function (tooltipItems,){
                          if (tooltipItems.value > ((50/100) * maxValue)){
                            return 'busy';
                          }else if (tooltipItems.value < ((30/ 100) * maxValue) ){
                             return ' not busy';
                          }else if ( tooltipItems.value < ((40/ 100) * maxValue )){
                            return 'kind of busy'
                          }
                      }
                }
              },
              scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    max: this.maximumValue,
                    display: true,
                  }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                  zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                  display: false,
                  drawBorder: false,
                  },
              }],
            },
          }
        },
    
      },
      mounted() {
        this.loadData()
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking your code, I noticed that you are using the `datasets` and `maximumValue` in data function.
To update the chart data based on dataset and maximumValue, you need to use those variables in computed data, not data.
For example,

```
computed: {
   chartData() {
      let chartData = {
         labels: [],
         datasets: [...],
      }
      return chartData;
   },
   maximumValue() {
      return this.maxValue;
   }
},
methods: {
  renderBarChart() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  max: this.maximumValue
              }
          }],
        },
      }
    });
  },
},
```

Comment: I tried understanding what you mean, but I cant really translate this into code, could you elaborate? the dataset and maximum value are being updated though, its just the chart yaxis  that is not rerendering

Comment: I understand your question, 
You are setting yAxes max value by global Chart setting.
But It doesn't work, you need to specify chart instance.
please try this.
`barChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = maxValue;`
`barChart.update();` 
instead of 
`Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.max = maxValue;`

Comment: https://codepen.io/endmaster0809/pen/bGpgmmw
In this codepen, I set max value as 55 by using `Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.max = 55`.
and later I reset it to 65 by using `barChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = 65; barChart.update();`

Comment: I don't think this solution is working for me. I think it has to do with the fact that I am using Vue-chartjs which is a wrapper around the chart.js. I am also using a premade BarChart component that i dont fully understand, hence why i am struggling to find a way to pass the options as props so to speak. I dont think i understand anything at this point :))

Comment: I have updated the code a bit. I kind of found a work around by using a boolean, but i am not happy with the result it gives